# Gson is crashing with Failed to invoke protected java.text.NumberFormat() with no args error

Tags: java, gson

I want to use gson to store and retrieve Event objects. Gson seems to handle converting to json correctly but it's crashing on the gson.fromJson() method. I am not sure how to proceed.

```
public static void putValue(Context ctx, Event event){
        //get preferences
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(event);       
        Log.i(TAG, "saving "+EVENT_KEY +Integer.toString(event.getId()));
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(EVENT_KEY + Integer.toString(event.getId()), json);
        editor.commit();
        //testing 
        String json2 = prefs.getString(EVENT_KEY + Integer.toString(event.getId()), null);
        Event savedEvent = gson.fromJson(json2, Event.class);
        if(savedEvent !=null){
            Log.i(TAG, "yup");
        }
        else{
            Log.i(TAG, "nope");
        }
    }
```

**Event class:**
https://gist.github.com/Janek2004/9950294

**Error:**

```
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793): Process: com.itenwired.itenconference, PID: 18793
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke protected java.text.NumberFormat() with no args
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793):    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:107)
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:162)
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793):    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793):    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793):    at com.itenwired.itenconference.model.MyEventManager.putValue(MyEventManager.java:37)
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793):    at com.itenwired.itenconference.adapter.AgendaAdapter$EventHolder$1.onClick(AgendaAdapter.java:88)
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100)
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class java.text.NumberFormat
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793):    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:104)
04-03 02:58:54.597: E/AndroidRuntime(18793):    ... 23 more
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes. I stopped using Gson.

Comment: I had the same problem. I solved removing this from the class variable:
  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy EEE", Locale.ITALY);

You should start to remove instance variable to find the one that cause the error.

Comment: @JanuszChudzynski What you have used for these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Accollativo and storm143 said, this is a problem with 
`SimpleDateFormat`. If you want to keep `SimpleDateFormat` as an instance variable, you can fix this by using an `ExclusionStrategy`.

```
public class GsonDeserializeExclusion implements ExclusionStrategy {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
        return f.getDeclaredClass() == SimpleDateFormat.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

You can then create a `Gson` instance with this exclusion using the `GsonBuilder`.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .addDeserializationExclusionStrategy(new GsonDeserializeExclusion())
        .create();
```

Comment: I am getting the same error but it was giving on third party library bean and I can't check where it is coming. Please help me how can I detect and skip that field

Answer (score 3):

It's a definitely a problem with `SimpleDateFormat`, as I had the same problem and followed Accollativo's adivce, and that fixed the bug for me. Very weird.

I realized I didn't actually need the `SimpleDateFormat` as a variable of the class, I instead just put it in the method where needed, so `GSON` didn't have to store the `SimpleDateFormat` object. Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Another fix for this is to add the transient keyword to the NumberFormatter so gson doesn't try and convert it into the json string. Which is fine since you don't need to save any values just make a new one when the class gets recreated.

For example

```
private transient NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
```